# Pythion: Conditional_join janitor package

Tags: python, pandas, pyjanitor

Hi I want to do a lookup to get the factor value for my dataset based on 3 conditions. Below is the lookup table:

```
Lookup_Table = {'State_Cd': ['TX','TX','TX','TX','CA','CA','CA','CA'],
        'Deductible': [0,0,1000,1000,0,0,1000,1000],
                'Revenue_1': [-99999999,25000000,-99999999,25000000,-99999999,25000000,-99999999,25000000],
                'Revenue_2': [24999999,99000000,24999999,99000000,24999999,99000000,24999999,99000000],
                'Factor': [0.15,0.25,0.2,0.3,0.11,0.15,0.13,0.45]
        }   
Lookup_Table = pd.DataFrame(Lookup_Table, columns = ['State_Cd','Deductible','Revenue_1','Revenue_2','Factor'])
```

lookup output:

```
Lookup_Table
State_Cd    Deductible  Revenue_1   Revenue_2   Factor
0   TX             0    -99999999   24999999    0.15
1   TX             0    25000000    99000000    0.25
2   TX          1000    -99999999   24999999    0.20
3   TX          1000    25000000    99000000    0.30
4   CA             0    -99999999   24999999    0.11
5   CA             0    25000000    99000000    0.15
6   CA          1000    -99999999   24999999    0.13
7   CA          1000    25000000    99000000    0.45
```

And then below is my dataset.

```
Dataset = {'Policy': ['A','B','C'],
        'State': ['CA','TX','TX'],
                'Deductible': [0,1000,0],
                'Revenue': [10000000,30000000,1000000]          
        }   
Dataset = pd.DataFrame(Dataset, columns = ['Policy','State','Deductible','Revenue'])
```

Dataset output:

```
Dataset
Policy  State   Deductible  Revenue
0   A   CA         0       1500000
1   B   TX         1000    30000000
2   C   TX         0       1000000
```

So basically to do the lookup the State must be matching to the State_Cd in lookup table, Deductible should be matching on the deductible in the lookup table, and lastly for Revenue it should be in between Revenue_1 and Revenue_2 (Revenue_1<=Revenue<=Revenue_2). To get to the desired factor value. Below is my expected output:

```
 Policy   State   Deductible  Revenue    Factor
    0   A   CA             0    1500000     0.11
    1   B   TX          1000    30000000    0.30
    2   C   TX             0    1000000     0.15
```

I'm trying the conditional_join from janitor package. However I'm having an error. Is there something missing on my code?

```
import janitor

Data_Final = (Dataset.conditional_join(Lookup_Table,
          # variable arguments
          # col_from_left_df, col_from_right_df, comparator
          ('Revenue', 'Revenue_1', '>='), 
          ('Revenue', 'Revenue_2', '<='),
          ('State', 'State_Cd', '=='),
          ('Deductible', 'Deductible', '=='),
          how = 'left',sort_by_appearance = False
             ))
```

Below is the error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copy'
```

Comment: what pandas version are you on?  An [issue](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/issues/1174) has been raised to address this, and there is a pending [PR](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/pull/1175) to resolve this. If you are on Pandas < 1.5, it should work. are you using the dev version of pyjanitor as well?

Comment: Also, if your data isn't large, and there are not so many duplicates, you can use the classic pandas merge and filter approach

Comment: I'm on pandas 1.5, and my janitor is 0.23.1

Comment: Should I also install older version of janitor?

Comment: No you don't need an older version of janitor. I would suggest you install the dev version if you can, as it offers more perf generally

Comment: Try pandas 1.4x - it should work ...

Comment: What's the dev version of janitor? I only run this code. pip install pyjanitor. Is this fine?

Comment: Oh that's fine. Is your code working now?

Comment: Yes my code works now, Thanks. I just made my pandas to be 1.4 version. pip install pandas==1.4

Comment: Cool you can close the question or post an answer to close it

Comment: Just a question. If there will be a new pandas version like 1.6, will it be fixed already? Like there's no need to install older version.

Comment: Yes, in the next release it will be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. By installing older version of pandas (less than 1.5). e.g.:

```
pip install pandas==1.4
```